# Cannot find sql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

Can anybody spot my syntax error? I am new to sql queries. This code is used elsewhere in my project and I reformated it for new tables I created but I get the following error with it:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_prescriptions ta, tbl_prescriptions_type tat, tbl_prescriptions_subtype' at line 1
QUERY:SELECT ta.pk_id, ta.date, tat.vch_type as vch_type_name, tar.vch_subtype as vch_subtype_name, concat(tas.vch_first_name, ' ', tas.vch_last_name) as vch_resource_name, FROM tbl_prescriptions ta, tbl_prescriptions_type tat, tbl_prescriptions_subtype tar, tbl_resources tas WHERE ta.fk_type_id = tat.pk_id AND ta.fk_resource_id = tas.pk_id AND ta.fk_subtype_id = tar.pk_id AND ta.fk_patient_id = 359 ORDER BY date DESC;`

```
$sqlPrescriptionQuery = "SELECT ta.pk_id, ta.date, ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "tat.vch_type as vch_type_name, ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "tar.vch_subtype as vch_subtype_name, ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "concat(tas.vch_first_name, ' ', tas.vch_last_name) as vch_resource_name, ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "FROM tbl_prescriptions ta, tbl_prescriptions_type tat, tbl_prescriptions_subtype tar, tbl_resources tas ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "WHERE ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "ta.fk_type_id = tat.pk_id AND ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "ta.fk_resource_id = tas.pk_id AND ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "ta.fk_subtype_id = tar.pk_id AND ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "ta.fk_patient_id = ".$row['pk_id']." ";
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "ORDER BY date DESC;";

$counter = 0;

$prescriptionresult = mysql_query($sqlPrescriptionQuery) or die(mysql_error()."<br>QUERY:".$sqlPrescriptionQuery);
```

Thanks !!

Comment: comma FROM ? Maybe if you didn't stick all that junk in there, you'd spot it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma too much at the end here:

```
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "concat(tas.vch_first_name, ' ', tas.vch_last_name) as vch_resource_name, ";
```

It should be:

```
$sqlPrescriptionQuery .= "concat(tas.vch_first_name, ' ', tas.vch_last_name) as vch_resource_name ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sqlPrescriptionQuery = "
SELECT ta.pk_id
     , ta.date
     , tat.vch_type vch_type_name
     , tar.vch_subtype vch_subtype_name
     , CONCAT(tas.vch_first_name, ' ', tas.vch_last_name) vch_resource_name
  FROM tbl_prescriptions ta
     , tbl_prescriptions_type tat
     , tbl_prescriptions_subtype tar
     , tbl_resources tas 
 WHERE ta.fk_type_id = tat.pk_id 
   AND ta.fk_resource_id = tas.pk_id 
   AND ta.fk_subtype_id = tar.pk_id 
   AND ta.fk_patient_id = $row['pk_id']
 ORDER 
    BY date DESC;
    ";
```